# Can I extend variant in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I'm not sure that this is possible, but say I have:

`using my_variant = std::variant<Class1, Class2, Class3>;`

Now at some point, I create a `Class4` and would like to extend `my_variant2` to include all of `my_variant` along with `Class4` (in a general way, i.e. not just using another `using...`) so that I can do something like create an array `std::array<my_variant2, n>`.

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[godbolted](https://godbolt.org/z/iXkzwU)

```
#include <variant>

template <typename T, typename... Args> struct concatenator;

template <typename... Args0, typename... Args1>
struct concatenator<std::variant<Args0...>, Args1...> {
    using type = std::variant<Args0..., Args1...>;
};

int main() {
    using type_t = std::variant<int, char, double>;
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<
            concatenator<type_t, float, short>::type,
            std::variant<int, char, double, float, short>>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward. I'm surprised the most complex answers have more upvotes than this.

Comment: @CássioRenan - I know!

Comment: Interesting. This makes, I guess, `std::variant` into a noncommutative monoid with identity `std::variant<>`.

Comment: @Sebastian - made me google what `monoid` is (finally), but agree, seems that way, like any other variadic template, in principle.

Answer (score 11):

There are two steps to achieving this. The first is to identify the list of types used in the original `std::variant` and the second is to construct a new `std::variant` type with the original arguments plus the one to add.

Partial template specialization can be used to write a trait that will obtain the list of template types used in a given `std::variant` :

```
#include <variant>

template<class T>
struct t_variant_cat;

template<class ... Old>
struct t_variant_cat<std::variant<Old...>> {
    // Old is a parameter pack containing all of 
    //  template arguments of the std::variant
};
```

Next we add another template argument that specifies the type to add and define an alias for this new type.

```
#include <variant>

template<class T, class New>
struct t_variant_cat;

template<class ... Old, class New>
struct t_variant_cat<std::variant<Old...>, New> {
    using type = std::variant<Old..., New>;
};
```

`typename t_variant_cat<my_variant, Class4>::type` should now yield  `std::variant<Class1, Class2, Class3, Class4>`. For convenience we can add a type alias to avoid having to write `typename` and `::type` each time :

```
template<class Old, class New>
using t_variant_cat_t = typename t_variant_cat<Old, New>::type;
```

The usage would be :

```
#include <variant>

template<class T, class New>
struct t_variant_cat;

template<class ... Old, class New>
struct t_variant_cat<std::variant<Old...>, New> {
    using type = std::variant<Old..., New>;
};

template<class Old, class New>
using t_variant_cat_t = typename t_variant_cat<Old, New>::type;

using old = std::variant<int, float>;
using extended = t_variant_cat_t<old, double>;

// Makes sure this actually works
static_assert(std::is_same_v<extended, std::variant<int, float, double>>,
    "Something is wrong.");
```

Comment: The question is incorrectly tagged with `C++14` (although `std::variant` is only there in `C++17`). Assuming that, you can chop 7 bytes from your example by using `std::is_same_v` instead of `std::is_same<>::value`, and another 2 bytes by not defining the t_variant_cat, it only needs to be declared :-D

Comment: @bobah Thank you for your feedback. I'll make that change.

Answer (score 8):

```
namespace impl_details {
  template<class Var, class...Ts>
  struct extend_type;
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Vs, class...Ts>
  struct extend_type<Z<Vs...>, Ts...> {
    using type=Z<Vs..., Ts...>;
  };
}
template<class Var, class...Ts>
using extend_type = typename impl_details::extend_type<Var, Ts...>::type;
```

now

```
extend_type<my_variant, Class4>
```

is

```
std::variant<Class1, Class2, Class3, Class4>
```

althought I disapprove of your 1-based indexing.

`extend_type< std::tuple<a,b,c>, d, e, f >` also works.

I can have some fun with this...

```
namespace impl_details {
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  struct type_cat;
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Lhs, class...Rhs>
  struct type_cat<Z<Lhs...>, Z<Rhs...>> {
    using type=Z<Lhs..., Rhs...>;
  };
}
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
using type_cat = typename impl_details::type_cat<Lhs, Rhs>::type;


auto variant_trinary( bool b ) {
  return [b](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) {
    using R=type_cat< std::decay_t<decltype(lhs)>, std::decay_t<decltype(rhs)> >;
    auto as_R = [](auto&&x)->R{ return decltype(x)(x)); };
    if (b)
      return std::visit( as_R, lhs );
    else
      return std::visit( as_R, rhs );
  };
}
```

which gives us the trinary operator on two variants.

```
auto var = variant_trinary(bool_expr)( var1, var2 );
```

where `var` is the concatination of the variant types of `var1` and `var2`.

Answer (score 1):

[bobah's answer here is very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52393977), but it wasn't clear to me how to handle the runtime part of this, of how to actually merge these objects at runtime.

Obviously a big if-chain is an option, but there's actually a different, more concise, way to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

template <typename T, typename... Args> struct concatenator;

template <typename... Args0, typename... Args1>
struct concatenator<std::variant<Args0...>, Args1...> {
    using type = std::variant<Args0..., Args1...>;
};

int main() {
    using typea_t = std::variant<int, char, double>;
    using typeb_t = concatenator<typea_t, float, short>::type;

    float foo = 0.1f;
    typea_t bar{12.0};

    typeb_t foobar = foo;
    std::visit([&](auto&& value) { foobar = value; }, bar);

    std::visit([](auto&& value) { std::cout << value << std::endl; }, foobar);

    return 0;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:29,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:29,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:29,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:29,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename...+Args%3E+struct+concatenator%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Args0,+typename...+Args1%3E%0Astruct+concatenator%3Cstd::variant%3CArgs0...%3E,+Args1...%3E+%7B%0A++++using+type+%3D+std::variant%3CArgs0...,+Args1...%3E%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++using+typea_t+%3D+std::variant%3Cint,+char,+double%3E%3B%0A++++using+typeb_t+%3D+concatenator%3Ctypea_t,+float,+short%3E::type%3B%0A%0A++++float+foo+%3D+0.1f%3B%0A++++typea_t+bar%7B12.0%7D%3B%0A%0A++++typeb_t+foobar+%3D+foo%3B%0A++++std::visit(%5B%26%5D(auto%26%26+value)+%7B+foobar+%3D+value%3B+%7D,+bar)%3B%0A%0A++++std::visit(%5B%5D(auto%26%26+value)+%7B+std::cout+%3C%3C+value+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+%7D,+foobar)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g122,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)