# Push Back an Element to a Vector of Std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm having problems creating a `push_back` function for an `std::vector` of `std::variants`. This is a minimal implementation of my struct so far:

```
template<class T, class Ts...> //Must construct with at least 1 argument
struct entity_container
{
  entity_container(T arg1, Ts ...args) //constructor, populate vector of std::variant's
  {
    entities.push_back(std::forward<decltype(arg1)>(arg1));

    auto loop = [&](auto&& arg)
    {
      entities.push_back(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
    }
    (loop(args),...);
  }
  
  std::vector<std::variant<T, Ts...>> entities;
}
```

Now suppose I want to add a `push_back` function then there are some things I considered:

- if we are adding a type which already exists in the `std::variant` of `entity_container::entities` then we can simply use: `entities.push_back(entity)`
- if we are adding a *new* type to `entity_container::entities` then we need to extended the type of the `std::variant`, then create a new `std::vector` of said type and move all the elements from the old vector to the new one.

for this second case, I came across two posts:

[extending a variant type in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393831/can-i-extend-variant-in-c) and
[copy/move elements between two std::variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246573/how-to-copy-an-element-of-stdvariant-to-a-variable-of-another-variant-type)

So using these tools this is what I *wanted* to do for my `push_back` implementation:

```
template<typename E>
void push_back(E&& entity)
{
  if( /* E is a new type to the variant */)
  {
    //std::variant<Old..., New>  =  std::variant<Old...> + New
    using extended_type = t_variant_cat_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(Entities[0])>, 
                                          std::remove_reference_t<E>>;

    //construct (with the new element) a new entity_container with the extended type, 
    entity_container<extended_type> entities_new(entity);

    //move the entities from the old container to the new one
    for(auto& ent : Entities)
      entities_new.entities.push_back(std::move(ent));    //all entities are moveable types

    //update replace the old container with the new
    entities = entities_new;
  }
  else /* E is not a new type to the variant */
  {
    entities.push_back(entity);
  }
}
```

But there are many, *many* problems with this.

1. How can we check that the type `E` is a new type to the variant?
2. `extended_type` would be something along the lines of `std::variant<T1, T2, T3, T4>` but in reality we have to construct an `entity_container` as `entity_container<T1, T2, T3, T4>` - how can we convert from an `std::variant` to a type pack?
3. when we do `entities = entities_new` at the end, these two objects have different types and therefore cannot be assigned to one another (and that's even if (2) could be fixed)
4. Finally, we have to reconstruct the container *every single time* an element is pushed back. That's gonna be really slow.

**So my overall question is, does anyone have any ideas to fix the above problems, or perhaps a whole new approach to writing this function.**

Side Note, the structure is used as so:

```
template<class T>
struct Entity{};

Entity<A> entity_a;
Entity<B> entity_b;
Entity<C> entity_c;

entity_container c(entity_a, entity_b);

c.push_back(entity_c);
```

Comment: This is setting off a lot of alarm bells for me.  Mainly due to the awkward mixture of runtime and compile-time concepts.  If you want this to compile at all, you will either need all potential types to be known up-front, some form of type erasure, or (as you mentioned in #4) you have to copy the entire container into a potentially new type every time an element is added.

Comment: For an alternative approach, consider the `object_t` being put into a `Table` in my answer to a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743699/4641116

Comment: @0x5453 yeah, im starting to think this approach is a dead end. Even if it worked, it'd be slow

Comment: @jf192210 Since `Entity` is a template, presumably you know all of the potential contained types (`A`, `B`, `C`, etc) at compile time?  `std::vector<std::variant<A, B, C>>` might be all you need.

Comment: well, it would be `std::vector<std::variant<Entity<A>, Entity<B>, Entity<C>>>`, and the thing is, thats fine but if you were to `push_back` an `Entity<D>` then you need to extend the type of the variant, and we see the problems i described in my post